# Set SVG Animation as background image - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, svg

**Hello everyone**

Im having trouble getting my svg animation as background/backgroundImage. I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
background: `url(${animation})`
```

or

```
backgroundImage: `url(${animation})`
```

When i load my svg animation like this. The SVG will show up, but without any animation.

When i use an object it does work. That looks something like this:

```
<object  type="image/svg+xml" data={animation} />
```

How can i set an SVG **Animation** as background. Any tips are welcome, please keep in mind that i am still a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of animation does it have? SVG as an image does not support scriping or interaction.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to wrap it in a div and use z-index to place it behind your container.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if background would work here. You may prefer to wrap it in a div and position it behind your container.

```css
body, html {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
  
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: magenta;
  opacity: 1;
  border: 10px dotted white;
  z-index: 0;
}

.content {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="background"></div>
 <div class="content">
  <p>Ipsum lorem this is fake content galorum.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```